# No error in CPLEX but there is no solution

Tags: node.js, arrays, error-handling, initialization, cplex

Here it is showing soc[t][number] is partially initiated. But I am only given the soc values for first hour and i want to update the value of soc in each hour.can I want to write soc as a decision variable?

```
int tavail=5; int n=10; range t=1..tavail; range number =1..n; float soc[t][number]=[[0.6,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9]]; //forcasted load at 0..4 float pl[t]=[10000000,7000000,9000000,6000000,12000000]; //target load at 0..11 float pt[t]=[10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000,10000000]; //bus voltage at 0..11 float v[t]=[240,232,229,233,230]; target bus voltage at 0..11 float vt[t]=[230,230,230,230,230]; //decision variable charging power ev dvar float pevch[t][number] in 0..100000; //decision variable discharging power of ev dvar float pevdis[t][number] in 0..100000; //objective function minimize sum(i in t)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in number)-pevch[i][j]+sum(j in number)pevdis[i][j]);

subject to

 forall(i in t,j in number:i!=tavail) if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && 0.7<soc[i][j]<0.9&& v[i]<vt[i]) pevdis[i][j]==soc[i][j]*100000;  soc[i+1][j]==0.8*soc[i][j];}    else  {pevdis[i][j]==0 ;  soc[i+1][j]==soc[i][j];}
     forall(i in t,j in number:i!=tavail)  if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && 0.3<= soc[i][j]<=0.7 && v[i]>vt[i])  {pevch[i][j]==soc[i][j]*800000;  soc[i+1][j]==1.1*soc[i][j];}    else  {pevch[i][j]==0;  soc[i][j]==soc[i][j];}  }
```